# Stripe payment for buyer and seller

Tags: php, stripe-payments

i am building an application that have two types users buyer and seller. now i want to Bayer pay to my stripe account using their credit card or debit card. and it is working fine.

but problem in i want to pay to seller from my stripe account using their credit card or debit card and i don't know about this.i am try to find in stripe website but can't understand. please help me if anybody implement that.

thanks.

Comment: sorry bro but Not understand what you want actually.

Comment: need to payment transfer from my stripe account to user credit card or debit card.

Comment: This has nothing to do with CakePHP, use tags that fit the question. Also SO is not a "write the code / tutorial for me" site. You need to show some code and effort. If you have trouble getting it done at all find somebody who can do it for you and pay them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Stripe Connect](https://stripe.com/connect) to process payments on behalf of other people.

Connect is a complex product so I recommend you take some time to browse through the [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect) as well as [this article](https://support.stripe.com/questions/considerations-for-platforms-using-connect) to find out if it'd be a good fit for your needs.

If you use Connect with [managed accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/managed-accounts), you can use debit cards as a payout method for US sellers. With standalone accounts, or non-US managed accounts, you can only use bank accounts as payout methods.